# How to check if one of the array value exist in a string?

Tags: jquery, arrays, string, search

I have three types of strings.

```
This is a test.

I am testing.

This is a simple string.
```

I want to get the string which does not contain `test` or `testing`. Which is the third string.

I have an array with values `test` and `testing`.

The only solution I have to loop over the array and search the array value in the string one by one.

```
$.each(myarray , function(index, val) { 
  if (string.indexOf(val) === -1) {

  }
});
```

Is there any better solution without a using a loop?

Comment: myarray contains two values `test` and `testing`

Comment: string is one of the three strings mentioned in the question.

Comment: so, your main question is how to check `myarray` strings are present in single `string` or not without loop?

Comment: my question is how to check myarray strings are not present in single string without a loop

Comment: I think you can simply do `if (string.indexOf(myarray[0]) === -1 && string.indexOf(myarray[1]) === -1) { .... }` then no loop is needed.

Comment: Array can contains more values. It is not restricted to two values only. This is only for example.

Comment: Then you can simply use regex and pass values in array to it like `if( string.match(/(test|testing)/g) )`.. here `match` returns null if no value is found in the `string`, if found it returns an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with the `some()` and the `includes()` function.
Here are informations about [some()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_some.asp) and [includes()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_includes.asp).

> The includes() method is case sensitive

To be a bit more precise, the `some` and the `includes` function runs through a loop in the background (under the hood). However, you do not need to write your own loop.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var strings = ['This is a test.', 'I am testing.', 'This is a simple string.'];
  var excludes = ['test', 'testing'];

  testFunction(strings, excludes);

  function testFunction(strings, excludes) {
    $.each(strings, function(index, string) {
      if (!excludes.some(v => string.includes(v))) {
        // here are just the strings which not includes substrings of "excludes"
       $('#output').append(string);
      }
    })
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<pre id="output"></pre>
```

Comment: I want to argue that "without writing a loop" is kind of misleading :D Under the hood `.some` and `.includes` do in fact also iterate over the given array. But the answer is correct nonetheless :)

Comment: @PhilippMeissner Thank you, I have added your reflections to my answer.